# Image upload success but it doesn't show the right path on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am uploading an image on my form then resizing it using a library. I can upload the pic with no problem here is my code:

```
public function store()
{
    $this->validate(request(),[

        'title'=>'required',
        'body'=>'required|min:5 ',
        'photo' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
    ]);



    $image = request()->file('photo');

    $fileName = $image->getClientOriginalName();

    $publicPath = 'images/';
    $image_resize = Image::make($image->getRealPath());
    $image_resize->resize(1200, 800);

    $image_resize->save($publicPath.$fileName);

        auth()->user()->addPost(new Posts( [
        'title'=>request('title'),
        'body'=>request('body'),
        'photo'=> $fileName

    ]));



    return redirect('/');
}
```

my issue is that the image doesn't show up on my front view. I have tried to remove the resizing its still the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the issue here is that when u are saving the post on database photo option u are saving only the filename, you should concatinate your public path with the image path like so: `'photo'=>  $publicPath.$fileName`

```
$image = request()->file('photo');

$fileName = $image->getClientOriginalName();

$publicPath = 'images/';
$image_resize = Image::make($image->getRealPath());
$image_resize->resize(1200, 800);

$image_resize->save($publicPath.$fileName);

    auth()->user()->addPost(new Posts( [
    'title'=>request('title'),
    'body'=>request('body'),
    'photo'=>  $publicPath.$fileName

]));
```

So try now it should work.